# Ruby not selecting correct overloaded method

Tags: ruby, rake, overloading

Ive got a simple Nunit runner for a rake script i have:

```
module NUnitRunner

    @NUnitPath = "#{RootDir}/tools/nunit/nunit-console.exe";

    def self.RunTests(testFile)
        system("\"#{@NUnitPath}\" ? \"#{testFile}\"")
    end

    def self.RunTests(testFile, runArgs)
        system("\"#{@NUnitPath}\" ? \"#{testFile}\" #{runArgs}")
    end

end
```

When im calling this module from within my task:

```
# Run Unit Tests
task :run_unit_tests do
    puts "Running Unit Tests"

    unitTestFile = "#{RootDir}/src/tests/unittests.dll"
    NUnitRunner.RunTests(unitTestFile)
end
```

It just keeps telling me "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)", and if i remove the overloaded method which takes 2 arguments it works fine, so is there some quirk with ruby that i dont know about in this instance?

Comment: check out http://albacorebuild.net - the Albacore gem is a suite of rake tasks for working with .net systems and includes an easy to use NUnit task. docs are here: http://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/wiki/NUnitTask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't support method overloading.

Comment: Oh right, so can only 1 signature exist for a given method? I assume it gets round this with optional arguments or something?

Comment: Grofit: Correct, only one signature can exist per method. You can declare optional arguments (default parameters). In some situations, you can also choose to override the method to achieve the effect (though, for what you describe, default parameters appears to be the best bet).